# Custom PhoneGap Plugin (iOS) Function Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, plugins, cordova

I'm using this tutorial to create a custom PhoneGap plugin: 
http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753496/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS

I have had success using the author's example, but I have a few questions that I have not been able to find out the answers to.

When the JavaScript function is created, the code is:

```
var MyPlugin = {

     nativeFunction: function(types, success, fail) {
          return PhoneGap.exec(success, fail, "PluginClass", "print", types);
     }
};
```

Is there a way to set this up without `var MyPlugin = {...};` and `nativeFunction`?  In other words, can we define a function of our plugin like  `myfunc = function()...`

Secondly, assuming there is a way to do the above, could this code:

```
MyPlugin.nativeFunction(
      ["HelloWorld"] ,
      function(result) {
           alert("Success : \r\n"+result);      
      },
      function(error) {
           alert("Error : \r\n"+error);      
      }
  );
```

(which is the test code to test the plugin) also be written in a more standardized way?  I.e., just a call to Javascript function without the `nativeFunction` part?

I would very much appreciate any input, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the phonegap documentation for plugins sucks. Honestly I had a bunch of issues when trying to create my own. A few tips :

the reason for doing

```
var MyPlugin = {};
```

is because this allows us to us scope things specific to that js object.
example:

```
MyPlugin.myFunction();
```

My favorite method to create plugins, similar to your question, is to prototype them

```
var MyPlugin = {}; // our object

MyPlugin.prototype.myFunction = function(success,fail,types){

}
```

The key to making a plugin fire is this -

```
PhoneGap.exec(success,fail,"MyPlugin","myFunction",types);
```

But something that they leave out is, what if we want to have options to our plugin? What if we want to do more than pass a string, then the example doesn't work. The fix is easy but not talked about at all.

```
var MyPlugin = {};
MyPlugin.prototype.myFunction = function(success,fail,options){
  var defaults = {
        foo: '', // these are options
        bar: '',
    };

    // this parses our "options"
    for(var key in defaults) {
        if(typeof options[key] !== "undefined") defaults[key] = options[key];
    }

    return PhoneGap.exec(success,fail,"MyPlugin","myFunction",[defaults]);
}
```

when we call this with out javascript -

```
var foo = MyPlugin.myFunction(success,fail,{
foo:'hello',
bar:'world'
});
```

You'll notice that most of the phonegap API uses this syntax, which I found strange that their documentation didn't really talk about how to do this.

I have a post about a plugin I create you can check it out for reference.
Blog - http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=138
Git - https://github.com/DrewDahlman/ImageFilter

Comment: be sure you're using the phonegap constructor - `PhoneGap.addConstructor(function () {
    if(!window.plugins) {
        window.plugins = {};
    }
    window.plugins. MyPlugin = new MyPlugin();
});`

Comment: Yeah it should go in your plugin js file - check out this git project - https://github.com/DrewDahlman/ImageFilter/blob/master/plugin/ImageFilter.js

Comment: one last thing - try to define the function like this `var MyPlugin = function(){};`